# JUnit: 4.8.1 "Could not find class"

Tags: java, junit4

Ok, I am like other and new to jUnit and having a difficult time trying to get it working. I have searched the forum but the answers provided; I am just not getting. If anyone out there could lend me a hand I would greatly appreciate it.

Let me provide the basics:
OS: mac OS X.6

```
export JUNIT_HOME="/Developer/junit/junit4.8.1"
export CVSROOT="/opt/cvsroot"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/localmysql/bin:/opt/PalmSDK/Current/bin/:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH:$JUNIT_HOME:$CVSROOT"
export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$JUNIT_HOME/junit-4.8.1.jar:$JUNIT_HOME"
```

I can compile a test class from a java file, however when I try to then run the test

```
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore MyTest.class
```

I get the following:

```
JUnit version 4.8.1
Could not find class: MyTest.class

Time: 0.001

OK (0 tests)
```

Now I have been in the directory with the `MyTest.class` which is just somewhere in my file system, I tried moving the source folder to the `junit` folder and the `junit/junit4.8.1` folder and the same result.  I cannot even run the tests that came with junit.

Comment: Did you try to add current directory to CLASSPATH? I.e. export CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH:[etc...]

Comment: Thanks for posting, no I shouldn't need it. Turned out to be simple typing mistake

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is `MyTest` really in the default package? If not, then you need to give the entire package-qualified name. In other words, if MyClass has a statement

```
package com.myself;
```

and lives in

```
/myproject/src/com/myself/MyClass.java
```

and you compiled into

```
/myproject/classes
```

then `/myproject/classes` must be on your `CLASSPATH` and you must

```
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.myself.MyTest
```

Come to think of it, I see now that you're appending `.class` to the class name, so even if it's in the default package, you should just say

```
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore MyTest
```

Comment: Yeah, including the ".class" was part of my problem as was not using the right case. Once I fixed that I was ok. I didn't need to worry about the classpath since it is just in the default package.

Comment: Thank you, this old post solved my problem as well. Including the .class files in the class path did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

Remove .class from MyTest.class i.e.
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore MyTest

Comment: I honestly feel a little silly, looks like my problem was forgetting that the java command is case sensitive. Once I typed it out with the right case then it worked just fine. 

Thank you to everyone that got back to me so promptly! I appreciate all of your help and will most certainly refer back to this thread when I try testing a more complex project.

Thanks again
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

It is not having problems finding JUnit -- it is finding that okay. It can't find MyClass, so the directory of that class (given that it is packageless) needs to be in the classpath.

Comment: That is was I was thinking but turns out it was my mistake. Thanks for the advice.