# JUnit "Could not find class: MyClass"

Tags: junit4

I have this project from Eclipse (where everything works fine) which I copied over to a different folder and tried running the JUnit tests. All the files are in the same folder (default package). The original structure of the folder was:
Project
  src
  bin

I have 2 source files and 1 test file in the src directory.
I copied the junit-4.11.jar into jre/lib/ext so that it is loaded by default. I run the java commands from the src folder and keep getting the error:
"Could not find class: MyClass"

I even tried adding the current folder to the classpath, but to no avail.

```
java -cp . org.junit.runner.JUnitCore MyClass
```

I have checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472408/junit-4-8-1-could-not-find-class), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667436/could-not-find-class-java-junit) and many other such posts. But none of them seem to work for me. I then tried moving the code up into the top directory without success.
Currently, I have the code in Desktop/MyClassFolder/ (on a Windows machine). I removed the "src" directory. I also tried the same stuff on a fedora machine with no success and also using JUnit 3.8. I must be missing something simple. Driving me nuts. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure that it's causing your problem, but I would not put the junit jar in jre/lib/ext. Put it on the classpath instead. Also try using packages. Using the default package is never a good idea. Oh, and make sure that the directory containing your compiled class (or the root of the package structure if you are using packages) is also on the classpath.

Comment: I have moved the stuff into a package. So the directory structure is now:

    root

       MyPackage

         MyClasses

It compiled fine. But I still get the same error. Should I be changing the command I run? I have added the root folder into the classpath and use myPackage\MyClass at the end of the java command

Comment: That seems to be correct, but make sure that the .class files are in the classpath, not just the .java files

Comment: Looks like it was an issue with junit-4.11.jar. Things work fine with junit-4.10.jar

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was an issue with junit-4.11.jar. Things work fine with junit-4.10.jar.